# What are the image file requirements for the Profile Picture

Tags: discussion

What are the recommended dimensions/size/resolution for the profile picture? I'd like to resize the image file to fit nicely within the allocated area for the profile picture, but I don't know the dimensions of that area.

Answer (score 2):

According to your current randomly generated one, it is 330x330 pixels in size.

I got this information by rightclicking on your profile picture and selecting "View Image".

Comment: Inspect element says it's 164x164. I don't have a 'view image' on right click. https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLA9f.png [My own avatar pics were uploaded at 128x128, but idk where I got that info from, they now also show as 164sq]

Comment: 328 (I rounded up to 330) is double that of 164 which is needed for retina displays.